# how to read Jsonp using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

How to read the values from json?, below is the output I am getting

```
jsonp1385632915442([{"Article":"<p>The <em>Wall Street Journal<\/em>test</p>"}]);
```

below is What I tried but no luck.

```
$.getJSON('https://xyz.com/Service.svc/GetdataById?callback=?',
    { id: id }, function (data) {
        $("#output").text(data['Article']);
    }
);
```

Comment: Use [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: That is not JSON, it is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: I have updated the code, sorry was not very clear earlier.

Comment: Got it working, This is how I did it:$("#output").append(data[0]['Article'] +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please first include jquery library in your project like.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

and then write bellow method in your java script.

```
function getJson(){
$.ajax({
   type: "Get",
        url: "http://www.json-generator.com/j/bUfoSqrjLS?indent=4",
        async: false,
       success: function(data){
      var len=data.length;
      for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var str=data[i].Article;
          alert(str);
      }
    },
   error: function(errorMsg){
    alert(errorMsg);
   }
});
```

}

after this call getJson method when click on button.

```
<input name="" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getJson();" />
```